# Embedding an entity refenrence add button on a q=node/view page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, entityreference

I am creating a 'Activity Management' site for that I have created 'Activity' and 'Participant' content types. 'Participant' content type has Full Name, Cell No, Email, Address fields and 'Activity' has title, location, time and activity participant - entity reference field of 'Participant' content type. I have created 'activity managers' role who can add/delete participant of an activity. I want to add two buttons on activity q=node/(view/display) page from where 'activity managers' can 1- Add new participant 2- Add from existing participant, to the activity. I have played around inline entity form, entity form but without luck. Inline entity form does it but on node/(add/edit) page not from q=node/view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using entity reference prepopulate module alongwith display suite or panels. 
I don't know much about panels but you can do this with display suite by adding a dynamic field and using the entity refrence prepopulate module (https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate). You can watch the code karate screencast (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9C4Uf6euLY) for entityreference prepopulate implementation(That's where I got this solution).

Hope this helps!